# Python - access class method (using twisted)

Tags: python, twisted

I'm working with [this example of an iPhone Chart Server](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/networking-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server) and all is working as expected.

What I wanted to ask is if and how I can use `message(self, message)` outside the `IphoneChat` class...

For example if I have an event triggering every hour I want to be able to send everyone connected a message or if I want to take the server down to send a 'global' announcement, do I have to put all the code within the `IphoneChat` class?

The `server.py` is this:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory, Protocol
from twisted.internet import reactor

class IphoneChat(Protocol):

    def connectionMade(self):
    self.factory.clients.append(self)
    print "clients are ", self.factory.clients

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
    self.factory.clients.remove(self)

# define message handling...

    def dataReceived(self, data):
    a = data.split(':')
    print a
    if len(a) > 1:
        command = a[0]
        content = a[1]

        msg = ""

        if command == "iam":
            #msg = content + " has joined"
            msg = "test1"   

        elif command == "toggle":
            #msg = command + ": " + content
            msg = "test2"

        elif command == "msg":
            msg = command + ": " + content
            print msg

        for c in self.factory.clients:
            c.message(msg)

    def message(self, message):
        self.transport.write(message + '\n')

rt = pollTimer.RepeatedTimer(3, NotifyAllFunction)

factory = Factory()
factory.protocol = IphoneChat
factory.clients = []
reactor.listenTCP(6035, factory)
print "chat server started"
reactor.run()
```

Adding the polling module:

```
from threading import Timer

class RepeatedTimer(object):
    def __init__(self, interval, function, *args, **kwargs):
    self._timer     = None
    self.interval   = interval
    self.function   = function
    self.args       = args
    self.kwargs     = kwargs
    self.is_running = False
    self.start()

    def _run(self):
    self.is_running = False
    self.start()
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

    def start(self):
    if not self.is_running:
        self._timer = Timer(self.interval, self._run)
        self._timer.start()
        self.is_running = True

    def stop(self):
    self._timer.cancel()
    self.is_running = False
```

Comment: I can't see how that would work in the current form, as `message` method includes `self.transport` and therefore needs to be a normal bound method. The method would break if it didn't have access to the `self` parameter.

Comment: I was planning to run a timer and fire and event every 60mins, but as mentioned without the self.transport everything I've tried fails... So in reality this example can't be used for this purpose, only to respond to incoming messages?

Comment: Trying now! Thanks a lot for your time Ashwini!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you registered a callback to be executed after some time, then you can simple access all the clients from `factory.clients` and send them a message using their `.transport.write()` method:

```
from twisted.internet import task

...
# Rest of the code
...

factory = Factory()
factory.protocol = IphoneChat
factory.clients = []

def broadcast(message):
    for client in factory.clients:
        client.transport.write(message + '\n')

event = task.LoopingCall(broadcast, 'Ping to all users')
event.start(60*60) # call every hour
reactor.listenTCP(6035, factory)
print "chat server started"
reactor.run()
```

Comment: With the polling method I have created it seems to give me the "Ping to all live users." only when I interact with the server, I get all the 'writes' together...

Comment: @Kostas Twisted already provides a function [`task.LoopingCall`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/14.0.2/api/twisted.internet.task.LoopingCall.html) that repeatedly calls a function after a certain amount of time. Why aren't you using it?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I just wanted to see if there is a more generic method to message all connected clients using this example as I will need it for what I have in mind for the next step of the app...

Comment: Tried with the task.LoopingCall as in your code but I get: `Unhandled error in Deferred:
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 69, in <module>
    event.start(3) # call every hour
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/twisted/internet/task.py", line 173, in start
    self()`

Comment: @Kostas It is working fine for me, looks like you're using different variable names than what you've posted in question body: i.e These 3 lines: `factory = Factory();factory.protocol = IphoneChat;factory.clients = []`

Comment: Yes you are right! I copied pasted and needed to add the definitions above the broadcast definition, I should have seen that it was using something not yet defined...! Awesome result! Many many thanks @Ashwini!